Vim: "not usable on this computer" error when trying to recover a swap file
I'd like to take a moment to touch on this error message, which can appear when you are listing swap files with vim -r.
 [not usable on this computer]

Wherein if you attempt to recover the swap file, vim will simply refuse and exit.
I encountered this error for the first time this week on a swap file and it drove me nuts. After googling to no avail, I spent over 6 hours bashing my head against the wall, reading thousands of lines of source code, dissecting the swap file format, editing swap files in a hex editor, comparing swap files byte by byte, and generally tearing my hair out trying to solve it.
I did, in fact, solve it. I now know way more than I ever wanted to know about Vim's inner workings, and I really feel like this needs to be documented somewhere.
This is a self-answer, but by all means, if you want to answer this question with your own information, or things that I didn't consider, please do. I learned what I learned by poring through Vim's source code. I'm sure someone else knows way more about this than I do.
Also note that I encountered this issue on a Windows system, but it can happen on any system Vim supports.

First off, let's demystify the header of the block zero file format vim uses. I'll start with a snippet from Vim's source code for the sake of completeness, though I do not expect every reader to read this.
// from memline.c
#define B0_UNAME_SIZE        40
#define B0_HNAME_SIZE        40
#define B0_FNAME_SIZE_ORG    900    // what it was in older versions

/* Note: the file name is actually 900 bytes, but the last two bytes are
 * always taken up by the flags and dirty byte (further below), this is
 * why I write it as [898] in the infographic. The dirty byte is defined
 * as 0x55, though I am unsure why it shows as 0x00 in the infographic.
 * The flags are 8 = has-fenc, 4 = same-directory, 3 = fileformat
 * (0 = null, 1 = unix, 2 = dos, 3 = mac)).
 */

#define B0_MAGIC_LONG     0x30313233L
#define B0_MAGIC_INT      0x20212223L
#define B0_MAGIC_SHORT    0x10111213L
#define B0_MAGIC_CHAR     0x55

struct block0
{
    char_u    b0_id[2];                    // id for block 0: BLOCK0_ID0 and BLOCK0_ID1,
                                           // BLOCK0_ID1_C0, BLOCK0_ID1_C1, etc.
    char_u    b0_version[10];              // Vim version string
    char_u    b0_page_size[4];             // number of bytes per page
    char_u    b0_mtime[4];                 // last modification time of file
    char_u    b0_ino[4];                   // inode of b0_fname
    char_u    b0_pid[4];                   // process id of creator (or 0)
    char_u    b0_uname[B0_UNAME_SIZE];     // name of user (uid if no name)
    char_u    b0_hname[B0_HNAME_SIZE];     // host name (if it has a name)
    char_u    b0_fname[B0_FNAME_SIZE_ORG]; // name of file being edited
    long      b0_magic_long;               // check for byte order of long
    int       b0_magic_int;                // check for byte order of int
    short     b0_magic_short;              // check for byte order of short
    char_u    b0_magic_char;               // check for last char
};

/*
 * Note: b0_dirty and b0_flags are put at the end of the file name.  For very
 * long file names in older versions of Vim they are invalid.
 * The 'fileencoding' comes before b0_flags, with a NUL in front.  But only
 * when there is room, for very long file names it's omitted.
 */
#define B0_DIRTY    0x55
#define b0_dirty    b0_fname[B0_FNAME_SIZE_ORG - 1]

/*
 * The b0_flags field is new in Vim 7.0.
 */
#define b0_flags    b0_fname[B0_FNAME_SIZE_ORG - 2]

// The lowest two bits contain the fileformat.  Zero means it's not set
// (compatible with Vim 6.x), otherwise it's EOL_UNIX + 1, EOL_DOS + 1 or
// EOL_MAC + 1.
#define B0_FF_MASK  3

// Swap file is in directory of edited file.  Used to find the file from
// different mount points.
#define B0_SAME_DIR 4

// The 'fileencoding' is at the end of b0_fname[], with a NUL in front of it.
// When empty there is only the NUL.
#define B0_HAS_FENC 8

/* Note: there is also stuff in here about encryption, which I have omitted
 * for the sake of brevity. You'll know your swap file is encrypted if the
 * signature is something other than `b0`. `bc` = zip encryption,
 * `bC` = blowfish, `bd` = blowfish2. See `:h 'cm'`
 */


Instead, I have prepared a handy infographic from a screenshot of a hexdump of a swap file, which is what I will be referring to throughout this answer.

I will try not to assume that everybody reading this is a C programmer. Let me know if the technical jargon is too much and I can try to amend it.

What I need to point your attention to is the last 4 items. The magics. There are two important considerations with these magic numbers: endianness and machine word size. My system, like most x86 machines these days, is a little-endian x86-64, and the OS I have running on it uses an ABI where sizeof (long) == 8 && sizeof (int) == 4 && sizeof (short) == 2 && sizeof (char) == 1. Due to the endianness, the bytes will appear "reversed" compared to the 0x format the constants are written in, and depending on your machine word size, the four magic numbers may have different sizes (the only thing that's actually likely to vary here is the longmagic, as sizeof (long) == 4 in most 32-bit ABIs). It's also worth noting that shortmagic is 4 bytes but it is stored in a short (which is 2 bytes) when being written to the file, so the order of the bytes on a little endian machine will be 13 12 11 10, and then, assuming sizeof (short) == 2 (you can refer to this wikipedia article for a more detailed overview of C integer types), it will be truncated to the first two bytes.
Assuming all little-endian, on a swap generated by a 64-bit version of Vim, you should expect to see this at offset +0x3f0:
3332 3130 0000 0000 2322 2120 1312 55

But for a 32-bit version of Vim, you will see this:
3332 3130 2322 2120 1312 55

If you look at the screenshot, you'll be able to deduce that the swap file being examined was generated by a 32-bit Vim.
The problem is that I have two versions of Vim on my system, a VIM 8.1 32-bit and a VIM 8.2 64-bit, and somehow never noticed this in 6 years of having this PC.
If you are also having this problem, that's probably what you need to check. You can do a hexdump of a swap file with xxd file paying attention to offset 000003f0 and you can check Vim's version and architecture information with the :version command.
I hope this saves someone else from the frustration of spending 6 hours digging through 5,000 lines of source code and tearing apart binaries in a hex editor just to figure out why they can't load a swap file.

I actually only spent one and a half hours digging through source code according to discord timestamps. No idea what I was doing for the other 4.5 hours, all I know is that I googled the issue today (yesterday) at around 14:00 and figured it out at 20:30 (it's 02:15 at the time of writing, I should go to sleep).
